# Es necesario realizar una taxonomia para cada custom post-types, en Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, php7

Estimad@, compañeros estoy realizando un custom posttype, sin embargo tengo la duda de que si se debe crear una taxomonia para cada custom post-type, que realice, o simplemente con disponer de uno es suficiente.
Sin embargo, la intriga que mantengo es, de que solo puedo resgistar un post-type, en la funcion de "register_taxonomy",y creo que deberia crear una a una.

```
<?php 

/* 
    Plugin Name: Pizzashop -  Specialities 
    Plugin URI: 
    Description: Add the post types to the website.
    Version: 1.0.0
    Author: Avellaneda
    Author URI: https://www.dixigunnpler.com
    Text Domain: pizzashop
    

*/

add_action( 'init', 'lapizzeria_especialidades' );

function lapizzeria_especialidades() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x('Especialidades', 'lapizzeria'),
        'singular_name'      => _x('Especialidad', 'post type singular name', 'lapizzeria'),
        'menu_name'          => _x('Especialidades', 'admin menu', 'lapizzeria'),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x('Especialidades', 'add new on admin bar', 'lapizzeria'),
        'add_new'            => _x('Agregar Nueva', 'book', 'lapizzeria'),
        'add_new_item'       => __('Agregar Especialidad', 'lapizzeria'),
        'new_item'           => __('Nueva Especialidad', 'lapizzeria'),
        'edit_item'          => __('Editar Especialidad', 'lapizzeria'),
        'view_item'          => __('Ver Especialidad', 'lapizzeria'),
        'all_items'          => __('Todas las Especialidades', 'lapizzeria'),
        'search_items'       => __('Buscar Especialidades', 'lapizzeria'),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __('Especialidad Padre', 'lapizzeria'),
        'not_found'          => __('No se encontraron especialidaides', 'lapizzeria'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No se encontraron especialidaides', 'lapizzeria')
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => __('Descripción.', 'lapizzeria'),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'menu-pizzeria' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => 6,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'         =>  array('categoria-menu'),
        'show_in_rest'       => true,
        'rest_base'          => "especialidades-api",
    );

    register_post_type('especialidades', $args);
}

/** Registrar una Taxonomia */

function lapizzeria_menu_taxonomia() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Categoria Menu', 'taxonomy general name', 'lapizzeria' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Categoria Menu', 'taxonomy singular name', 'lapizzeria' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Buscar Categoria Menu', 'lapizzeria' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'Todas Categorias Menu', 'lapizzeria' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Categoria Menu Padre', 'lapizzeria' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Categoria Menu:', 'lapizzeria' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Editar Categoria Menu', 'lapizzeria' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Actualizar Categoria Menu', 'lapizzeria' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Agregar Categoria Menu', 'lapizzeria' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'Nueva Categoria Menu ', 'lapizzeria' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categoria Menu', 'lapizzeria' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'categoria-menu' ),
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
        'rest-base'     => 'categoria-menu'
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'categoria-menu', array( 'especialidades' ), $args );
}

    add_action( 'init', 'lapizzeria_menu_taxonomia', 0 );

?>
```

Su gentil ayuda, si debo continuar por este camino.
lo agradezco de antemano, debido a que el sistema de consultas y categorizacion aun parece complejo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El parámetro `taxonomies` es totalmente opcional, el la propia documentación lo menciona

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#taxonomies

`(array) (optional) An array of registered taxonomies like category or post_tag that will be used with this post type. This can be used in lieu of calling register_taxonomy_for_object_type() directly. Custom taxonomies still need to be registered with register_taxonomy().`

Puedes omitirlo con toda confianza y si te es necesario agregas la taxonomía en cualquier otro punto de tu código.

---

Por otro lado volviendo a leer tu planteamiento, veo que estas leyendo mal la documentación `register_taxonomy` puede utilizarse para uno o múltiples post-type

En la documentación dice
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/
`$object_type (array|string) (Required) Object type or array of object types with which the taxonomy should be associated.`

por lo que podrías implementarlo así

`register_taxonomy( 'genero', array( 'peliculas', 'artistas', 'demos' ), $args );`

Comment: Muchas, gracias, si tenia esa duda, de crear varias taxonomias, por cada post-type. Mucahs gracias @ArturoGallegos